# Is CloudFront useful to speed up sequential file access within an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I need to process all the data (+10PB) of an S3 bucket using EMR or EC2 (I have implemented both methods).

Massively parallel access to the S3 results in "Slow Down 503" errors. I only want to read each object **once**.

Is CloudFront useful to prevent this error from happening? Is there any other way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: CloudFront would only be useful if your massively parallel processes are running outside of AWS. I assume you are running these processes inside AWS, in the same region as the S3 bucket?

Comment: @MarkB yes, I am running the process inside AWS in the same region.

Comment: I dont think Cloudfront will help, its a cache - using it from same region to request files once doesnt make sense and will be expensive. Do the keys for your S3 objects all have a common prefix? S3 shards content based on the key from left to right so if all your keys start e.g. `/some/common/prefix/` all your data will reside in relatively few shards - that could be a bottleneck. Also have you considered a VPC endpoint for s3? (check the docs first - there are caveats, but using the private ip means your shortening the journey to S3 from your VPC).

Comment: Best practices to [optimize speed between S3 and EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-transfer-data-bucket-instance/).

Comment: If you have not already done so, I _strongly_ recommend talking to your IT group before doing this, to ensure that a gateway endpoint is in place. Downloading 10 PB of data from S3 over a NAT will cost roughly a half million dollars.